# How to create a product options prices by customer group wise in opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart

I created two group one is A and other is B . i want there multiple option as each have different prices as acording to customer group i have some code but it does not run properly it give a message as  "Call to undefined method Cart\Customer::getCustomerGroupId() in C:\xampp\htdocs\postal\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-catalog_model_catalog_product.php on line 340".
the code is in vqmod xml file -`enter code here`

problem is there i can not know how to definde customer group id and this code is running in old version perfectly
the code is attach in link --  [product-option by **download-customer group**](http://messcleaners.co.nz/optionbycustomer/product_option_customer_group.xml)

please check this and send me how to define and fix the bug.
the code run proper before login- wen i login then give error message.

Comment: And problem is where? Try to create undefined method.

Comment: problem is that wen i login as a user then error meeasge to shown

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to modify system\library\cart\customer.php to:

/*create a function*/

public function getCustomerGroupId() {

```
    return $this->customer_group_id;

}
```